# about half of my if statements not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, printing

I am to make a python program using basic operators to ask for an income from the user, in order to calculate the 2017 progressive tax along with 2018. The output should look like this:

```
Income: 15000
2017 tax: (tax amount here) #will skip the math for samples
2018 tax: (tax amount here)
```

My program as of now produces both prints for 2017 / 2018 but will stop at the 2018 nested if bracket of 82501 to 157500 (which is nested in the 4th elif)... Here's my program as of now, since its long I'll mark out where it stops working.

```
income = float(input("Enter your income to calculate tax: "))

#Loop input/calculations
while income > 0:
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    if income >= 0 and income <= 9325:
        bracket1 = income * 0.10
        tax2017 = bracket1
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
        if income >= 0 and income <= 9525:
            newbracket1 = income * 0.10
            tax2018 = newbracket1
            print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    elif income >= 9326 and income <= 37950:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (income - 9326) * 0.15
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
        if income >= 9526 and income <=38700:
            newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
            newbracket2 = (income - 9525) * 0.12
            tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2
            print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    elif income >= 37951 and income <= 91900:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (income - 37951) * 0.25
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
        if income >= 38701 and income <= 82500:
            newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
            newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
            newbracket3 = (income - 38700) * 0.22
            tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3
            print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    elif income >= 91901 and income <= 191650:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (income - 91901) * 0.28
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
        if income >= 82501 and income <= 157500: #HERE STOPS WORKING, the 2018 from here on doesn't print
            newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
            newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
            newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
            newbracket4 = (income - 82500) * 0.24
            tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4
            print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    elif income >= 191651 and income <= 416700:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (191650 - 91901) * 0.28
        bracket5 = (income - 191651) * 0.33
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
        if income >= 157501 and income <= 200000:
            newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
            newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
            newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
            newbracket4 = (157500 - 82501) * 0.24
            newbracket5 = (income - 157500) * 0.32
            tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4 + newbracket5
            print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    elif income >= 416701 and income <= 418400:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (191650 - 91901) * 0.28
        bracket5 = (416700 - 191650) * 0.33
        bracket6 = (income - 416701) * 0.35
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + bracket6
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
        if income >= 200001 and income <= 500000:
            newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
            newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
            newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
            newbracket4 = (157500 - 82501) * 0.24
            newbracket5 = (200000 - 157501) * 0.32
            newbracket6 = (income - 200001) * 0.35
            tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4 + newbracket5 + newbracket6
            print("2018 tax: ",tax2018)
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    elif income >= 418401:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (191650 - 91901) * 0.28
        bracket5 = (416700 - 191650) * 0.33
        bracket6 = (418400 - 416700) * 0.35
        bracket7 = (income - 418401) * 0.396
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + bracket6 + bracket7
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",tax2017)
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))

    else:
        print("invalid")
```

I've marked the line that wont work. just to clarify, the nested if's and prints before that output both 2017 and 2018 results, but when the income is in the marked range and greater, only 2017's tax will print.

My outcome at income 82502 and above is something like:

```
Enter your income to calculate tax: 82502
----------------------------------------------
Income:  82502.0
2017 tax:  16364.00

Enter your income as and integer with no commas:
```

SOLVED:
thanks for all the comments and answers, they cleared some things up for me!
here is what I've reworked, seems to work so I'm satisfied. I'll be adding a few more calculations so hopefully that goes well too :)

```
income = float(input("Enter your income to calculate tax: "))

#Loop input/calculations
while income > 0:
    if income >= 0 and income <= 9325:
        bracket1 = income * 0.10
        tax2017 = bracket1
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 0 and income <= 9525:
        newbracket1 = income * 0.10
        tax2018 = newbracket1
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    if income >= 9326 and income <= 37950:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (income - 9326) * 0.15
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 9526 and income <=38700:
        newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
        newbracket2 = (income - 9525) * 0.12
        tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    if income >= 37951 and income <= 91900:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (income - 37951) * 0.25
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 38701 and income <= 82500:
        newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
        newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
        newbracket3 = (income - 38700) * 0.22
        tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    if income >= 91901 and income <= 191650:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (income - 91901) * 0.28
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 82501 and income <= 157500:
        newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
        newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
        newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
        newbracket4 = (income - 82500) * 0.24
        tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    if income >= 191651 and income <= 416700:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (191650 - 91901) * 0.28
        bracket5 = (income - 191651) * 0.33
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 157501 and income <= 200000:
        newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
        newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
        newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
        newbracket4 = (157500 - 82501) * 0.24
        newbracket5 = (income - 157500) * 0.32
        tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4 + newbracket5
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    if income >= 416701 and income <= 418400:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (191650 - 91901) * 0.28
        bracket5 = (416700 - 191650) * 0.33
        bracket6 = (income - 416701) * 0.35
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + bracket6
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 200001 and income < 500000:
        newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
        newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
        newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
        newbracket4 = (157500 - 82501) * 0.24
        newbracket5 = (200000 - 157501) * 0.32
        newbracket6 = (income - 200001) * 0.35
        tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4 + newbracket5 + newbracket6
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))
    if income >= 418401:
        bracket1 = 9325 * 0.10
        bracket2 = (37950 - 9325) * 0.15
        bracket3 = (91901 - 37950) * 0.25
        bracket4 = (191650 - 91901) * 0.28
        bracket5 = (416700 - 191650) * 0.33
        bracket6 = (418400 - 416700) * 0.35
        bracket7 = (income - 418401) * 0.396
        tax2017 = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + bracket6 + bracket7
        print("Income: ",income)
        print("2017 tax: ",format(tax2017,'.2f'))
    if income >= 500000:
        newbracket1 = 9526 * 0.10
        newbracket2 = (38700 - 9526) * 0.12
        newbracket3 = (82500 - 38701) * 0.22
        newbracket4 = (157500 - 82501) * 0.24
        newbracket5 = (200000 - 157501) * 0.32
        newbracket6 = (500000 - 200001) * 0.35
        newbracket7 = (income - 500000) * 0.37
        tax2018 = newbracket1 + newbracket2 + newbracket3 + newbracket4 + newbracket5 + newbracket6 + newbracket7
        print("2018 tax: ",format(tax2018,'.2f'))
        income = float(input("\nEnter your income as and integer with no commas: "))

    else:
        print("-------------------")
```

Comment: Why is the logic for each 2018 tax bracket nested inside the branch for a 2017 tax bracket?

Comment: It will never get to that line because its going into the elif above: `elif income >= 37951 and income <= 91900:` Use a debugger and step through your program to see the flow.

Comment: @user2357112 i should have mentioned, i'm very new.. i've only made a handful of other basic calculating programs.. this is the first one i'm trying with a loop, didn't realize there was a better way :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work through what statements the program will go through for

```
income =  82502.0
```

will enter

```
elif income >= 37951 and income <= 91900:
```

but for 2018 calculation, it won't satisfy the conditional inside it

```
    if income >= 38701 and income <= 82500:
```

So it has no way to calculate 2018. It will not get to the point where you marked it.

2017 calculation should be independent of 2018 calculations. There are lots of cases where your calculation will not print 2018 tax.

But you did have good testing to see that your program is not working. Edge cases generally give problems.

Comment: Wow thanks for helping out so quick! okay I see what you mean not sure how i missed that.. still confused on how to correct myself at this point but i'll give it a go.

Comment: do you think i could change the tab levels of the unnecessarily nested if's?

Comment: Yes, do 2017 first, print it out, and then do 2018 separately.